# How to use Greek characters/letters in a query?

Tags: categories, query, language

I have a problem with Greek characters in a query.

[Here is the code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3409)

Using the Greek characters in the 'meta_value' => 'Ναι' the query can't work, because of the language.

How can i make it work?

Comment: Why shouldn’t that work? What is the value of the constant `DB_COLLATE`?

Comment: @toscho, it was empty:

`define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

Comment: Use `utf8_unicode_ci` and try again.

Comment: @toscho, nothing changed. It gives me a blank category, when i just change the "Ναι" to "Yes" it gives me the posts in the category..

Comment: Enable the [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and inspect the actual database query.

Comment: @toscho , I know how to enable it `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` but don't know how to inspect the actual database query.

Comment: Install [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/).

Comment: @toscho, I installed it and getting in the category page, pushing the "Debug" button gives me 8 notices. Nothing else. What should i look?

Answer (score 0):

This is the loop I've created to display post's matching criteria on empty page:

```
// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'meta_key=apaitei_logariasmo_facebook&meta_value=Ναι' );

// The Loop
if( $the_query->have_posts() )
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<h3>'; the_title(); echo '</h3>';
        the_content();
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It works. Look at the image:

[image: Page with post listed]

Note: my site's language is English with:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

How do you know that your query returns no posts if you don't display anything. At least the code you provided does not show it.

Comment: i editted the main question and hyperlinked the code i use for the category template.